# Store coefficients in an array in header file ("does not name a type" error)

Tags: c++, arrays, header-files, numeric

I want to create a class to solve a numerical analysis problem, and I have to store somewhere an array of doubles that I will need several times. So I just created an header file to hold those constants

```
#ifndef COEFFS_H_
#define COEFFS_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;    

const int p = 8;

double alpha[p];
alpha[0] = 1.83;
alpha[1] = -7.15;
alpha[2] =  +9.43;
alpha[3] = -3.76;
alpha[4] = -2.34;
alpha[5] = +4.69;
alpha[6] = -2.78;
alpha[7] = +4.80;

#endif /* COEFFS_H_ */
```

In the main file I will need these values inside a for loop: I just did
`#include coeffs.h` , but once I compile the main, it gives me the error

`‘alpha’ does not name a type`

I'm a beginner, so I looked up almost everywhere here and on the web. I found similar problems of other people, but it seems always too much complicated. Is there a very easy  way to fix this?

Comment: Just a tip: don't use `using namespace` statements in headers. It'll cause you (and any collaborators or users) a lot of grief later on.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED thanks for your tip! May I ask why it's not good to be used? Is this because lots of people prefer ::?

Comment: It's not a matter of preference, but instead the fact that `using` brings a symbol (or in the case of `using namespace`, all of the symbols in a particular namespace) into the current scope - in this case, the "global" scope. If something else had e.g. `struct ostream{};` as a user defined type, using your header would cause a type conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two errors, first the correct syntax is this

```
double alpha[p] = { 1.83, -7.15, ... };
```

You can't write executable code outside of a function as you were doing.

Second even with this correct syntax by defining your array in a header file you are running the risk of multiple definition errors. The correct technique is to *declare* the array in a header file, and *define* it in an implementation file

```
// header file
extern double alpha[]; // declaration

// implementation file
#include "header file.h"

double alpha[p] = { 1.83, -7.15, ... }; // definition
```

Comment: Thanks @john. Everything is clearer now. Actually, the coefficients are numbers with lots of digits. So, after the declaration in the header, I wrote in the main 

` double alpha[p];
  alpha[0] = 1.8321743782540412751 * 1e-14; 
`
and so on for the others. It works. Could you tell me if there's a better way to write this definition?

Comment: @VoB The same syntax I described above will also work in `main`.